# Puphpet MySQL Workbench Connection in Vagrant on Cygwin

Tags: mysql, connection, vagrant, mysql-workbench, puphpet

I am new to programming, and do not have much idea about ports/forwarding/connection etc.

> Installed Vagrant, MySQL Workbench, and Cygwin on Windows 8.1, then
>   Puphpet on Cygwin and created Virtual Machine, for learning.

But, **unable to connect to MySQL on Virtual Machine** (MySQL Server is on, on Virtual Machine) **from Workbench in Windows**.

I did not do any change in *vagrantfile* or *config.yaml*.

Tried Out:

- Changed to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in *my.conf*, but no use.
- Commented out `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in *my.conf*, again 
  no use.

> Note: (I **DELETED id_rsa file** when it was not properly doing vagrant up
>   second time. So, gave full path to **id_rsa.ppk**, for connecting)

Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP over SSH)
Parameters:

```
Hostname:     192.168.56.101:8957
SSH Username: vagrant
SSH Password: vagrant
SSH Key File: c:\cygwin64\home\tomy\puphpet\sutfva\puphpet\files\dot\ssh\id_rsa.ppk
MySQl Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port:         3306
Username:     dbuser
Password:     123
```

Error message:

> IO Error [Errno 10061] No Connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it. Please refer to logs for details

The answer at [Vagrant MySQL Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750174/vagrant-mysql-access) is not clear to me. How to configure port forwarding?

Can you please guide me in simple words, how I can establish connection? Also, how to disconnect, and any security issue.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836246/how-do-i-sequel-pro-with-puphpet/28840978#28840978

Comment: Sir (Mr. Juan Treminio): Thank you very much for taking time to give me the right direction. Details about the connection is given below, so that it can be useful to beginners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much **Juan Treminio** and **Brian Morton**! Both of them gave valuable tips and inputs for me to come to track! **In addition, immense thanks to Juan Treminio for his https://puphpet.com** which is a huge help to persons like me.

COMPLETE Connection Details:

Choose
**Standard TCP/IP over SSH**

Parameters (Mostly **default values** since I did not change it)

```
SSH Hostname: 192.168.56.101
SSH Username: vagrant
SSH Password: vagrant
SSH Key File: C:\cygwin64\home\tomy\puphpet\sutfva\puphpet\files\dot\ssh\id_rsa
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQl Server Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: 123
```

Note: *Remember to note down your connection parameters*

Answer (score 0):

```
Hostname:     192.168.56.101:8957
```

You shouldn't need the port here, you should probably just need to ender `192.168.56.101`

To verify which port SQL Server is listening on, you can `ssh` into the box and run

```
netstat -lnutp
```

This will output a list of the currently open and listening ports on the box. If you do not see SQL Server in the list, then it is not currently running and the service will need to be started.

Comment: Sir (Mr. Brian Morton), Thank you very much! It was a huge tip for me. Using your inputs, I could make it. But, I gave detailed answer separately so that it may help beginners like me.

Comment: @Tomy glad I could help. If the problem is resolved, you should upvote the helpful answers and mark one as accepted.